# Executing computing multiple values in a single query in mysql

Tags: mysql

Coinsider two tables User and Posts with `1-N` relation between user-posts.
Is there a way I can execute a query in which I can return users with atleast one post, and users with more than 1 post.
[image]
I want the result to be like this
[image]

Explanation:
user 1 Has 3 Posts, so increment 1 on both count(1 or more post),count (more than 1) column   //category: Design
user 2 Has 2 Posts, so increment 1 on both count(1 or more post),count (more than 1) column // category: Engineering
user 3 Has 1 Post, so increment 1 on count(more than 1) column only. // category: Design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a double aggregation approach:

```sql
SELECT Category,
       SUM(cnt >= 1) AS cnt_1_or_more,
       SUM(cnt > 1) AS cnt_more_than_1
FROM
(
    SELECT u.Category, COUNT(p.user_id) AS cnt
    FROM User u
    LEFT JOIN Post p ON p.user_id = u.user_id
    GROUP BY u.Category, u.user_id
) t
GROUP BY Category;
```

Comment: Awesome, I made a small change to this query. I used Right Join instead of left join to remove any possible null values of the category. Of course I dint mention it beforehand in the question , realized it after trying the solution

Comment: @HussamKhatib I actually did see this in your expected output.  But I thought maybe you wanted to report all categories, in which case you would want left join.  Inner join also works though.

Comment: Also what does the "t"  after the end of from ( ... ). I did try to find on google , got nothing.

Comment: In most flavors of SQL (MySQL included), every derived table requires an _alias_.  The `t` is an alias for the derived subquery.